# Extracting starting and ending points from geometry column in separate columns using GeoPandas

Tags: shapefile, geometry, geopandas, vertices, xy

I have a line shapefile in GeoPandas. How can I extract the start and end coordinates as (x,y) pairs in two separate columns?

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(pth_line_shapefile)
gdf['start_coordinates_XY'] = gdf.apply(lambda x: [y[0] for y in x['geometry'].coords], axis=1)
```

The above code extracts X coordinates of all points in the geometry not the first point (in x,y format).

An example line shapefile linked [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/my9as72pasnb7z4/AADpePfb20hyNfLiSothjz0Ba?dl=0).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can make it:

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString

line1 = LineString([Point(0,0), Point(-1,-1), Point(2,-3), Point(4,5)])
line2 = LineString([Point(-2,8), Point(7,4), Point(0,-1), Point(0,2)])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    {'City': ['Buenos Aires','Rio de Janeiro'],
     'Country': ['Argentina', 'Brazil'], 'geometry': [line1, line2]})

gdf['first'] = None
gdf['last'] = None

for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    coords = [(coords) for coords in list(row['geometry'].coords)]
    first_coord, last_coord = [ coords[i] for i in (0, -1) ]
    gdf.at[index,'first'] = Point(first_coord)
    gdf.at[index,'last'] = Point(last_coord)
    gdf
```

Which results in:

[image: Results]

You can tweak that to suit what ever format your need for your points...

#### Source:

> Coordinate values are accessed via coords, x, y, and z properties.

https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#Point

#### Reference

Gillies, S. others.(2007). Shapely: Manipulation and analysis of geometric objects. toblerity. org.

Comment: Can one do that on a vectorized manner, that is avoiding `iterrows`?

Comment: You can try an element wise multiplication of your vector of coordinates with a vector of zeroes of the same length but where its first and last value equal to 1. Then drop all 0 and figure a way to use the result to suit your needs.

Answer (score 8):

It is easier to use **apply** and **lambda** functions:

```
import geopandas as gpd
gdf = gpd.read_file(pth_line_shapefile)

# Extract start and end coordinates of each linestring
first_coord = gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.coords[0])
last_coord = gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.coords[-1])

# Add start and end as columns to the gdf
gdf["start_coord"] = first_coord
gdf["end_coord"] = last_coord
```

Comment: This is much better (faster and more readable) than the accepted answer.